# Match queries that fit change snapshot

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, indexing

How can one store queries (like `match` from mongo, or a SQL `where` clause), and given a change snapshot of a single document (a delta of a single row/document) lookup which queries `COULD` match that change?

Example:
I have a simple query: `db.collection.find({name: "Ivan", status: "active"})` that gets stored as a json in the DB.
And a change occurs in the database, looking like: `{type: "update", $set: {name: "Ivan"}}`

I need to query a queries collection/table and find witch ones could have been impacted.

Limitations:

- There could be millions of queries stored, requiring a good index approach.
- The match could be limited to a few operands for simplicity (like $in, $eq, $ne)
- Mongodb change streams don't scale to millions, and Postgres LISTEN/NOTIFY doesn't as well.

Is there a pattern here that I'm missing?